# WordPress excerpt_more filter hook is not working only on the very first post of my blog page

Tags: wordpress, filter, hook

I have set a blog page that is separate from my static home page.

I have modified the “[...]” link that comes after each post’s excerpt on the blog page by using a filter function.

To do this, I used WordPress’s “excerpt_more” hook.

```
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
   global $post;
   return '... <br clear="all"/><a class="moretag" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">Continue Reading</a>';
}
```

The problem I am having is that, for some reason, this works for every post, *except* the very first post of the blog page.

Is there something different or special about the very first post of the blog page that would make it not go through this filter hook?

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this one:

```
 add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');

    function new_excerpt_more($more) {

       return '... <br clear="all"/><a class="moretag" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">Continue Reading</a>';
    }
```

Also, if in Wordpress a post has a manual excerpt, the `excerpt_more` filter wont get executed. So it's always recommended to check that, just in case.

Comment: Hi Tomas. Are you saying essentially that I should just remove the "global $post;" statement, and change "$post->ID" to "get_the_ID()" ?

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't fix the issue.  I currently think that it might be related to the way the WordPress theme works by default. But thanks for reminding me that I don't need to use "global $foo" inside functions, because there are built-in WP functions that get those variables.

Comment: @LeonardShelby, are the excerpt autogenerated? Because if the content is too short, depending on how you are implementing it, the "read more" isn't added.

Comment: Yes the excerpts are autogenerated.  It is the Genesis child theme Enterprise Pro.  I do not think that it is a problem of the content being too short.  The excerpt for the first post is actually longer than the excerpt for all the other posts, at 86 words.  For some reason, the excerpt for the first post is being displayed as the first full paragraph of the post, instead of the default excerpt size defined by WordPress, which is the first 55 words.  The excerpt for all other posts is the default 55 words.

Comment: I remembered one time I had a similar problem, it was generated by a manual excerpt in one of the posts. Can you add the loop's code?

Comment: That is strange that you say that.  My co worker found out that there was a manual excerpt in that very post that was not displaying a "Continue Reading" link.  WordPress does not have the excerpt field enabled by default in the edit post screen, so I did not see the manual excerpt.  I am kind of new at WordPress so I did not even realize that excerpt was a potential manual field.  So in sum, yes you were right, that was the issue.  You hit on it one day late, but considering you can't see the code like my worker, I think you deserve a point, but I don't have 15 reputation yet to upvote you.

Comment: @LeonardShelby, GREAT! It was literally a shower thought. I'll just add that to the answer, maybe we can save someone a couple of hours.